# When will "while(1) { sleep(1); }" die in PHP?

Tags: php, execution

I was just wondering today whether or not the script terminated when the user exit the webpage (while loading). It [turns out that yes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php), unless you set it otherwise. So, with that in mind, when does this script finish?

```
// Don't stop script even when the user closes the window
ignore_user_abort();

set_time_limit(0);

// Infinite loop (normally aborted when the user closes the window)
while(1) {
  sleep(1);
  }
```

My best bet is, when the PHP and/or the server is turned off/on. However, in a production system, this can be only in critical situations. So the question is, **when would the script normally be ended?** By normally I mean without any action being taken to end that specific script. Wouldn't the same script without the `sleep()` be a potential hazard for hosting companies? Set out one of them with a slightly expensive operation and the server is 100% for that script.

Comment: Unless the Apache server stops or you use some break point in your loop

Comment: Probably when the time comes, it would just casually die in it's sleep

Comment: PHP has a [max_execution_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) setting in PHP.INI which will limit the script. By default it's set to 30 seconds.

Comment: @MikeW He uses `set_time_limit(0);`. I believe than depends of the host, they commonly limit the set of max_execution_time by local php.ini. So if host if fully liberal this can happens.

Comment: I just don't get the purpose of this question.

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity. I want to know when are normally PHP scripts terminated. Is C, running the PHP script, able to determine that it should end a script under some circumstances or not?

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia there are many reasons for terminating a script: hitting limits (memory, time), causing errors (including uncaught exceptions), intentional exiting the script, terminating the interpreter (by killing the container e.g. apache). And yes, this can all happen in a `while(true) sleep(1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I am thinking of:

1. Apache restarted - Some hosting companies will do that if it reaches a CPU usage limit.
2. Some hosting companies will limit your processes to x number of processes at the same time (ex: 1and1). So once three people access your site, everyone else will get error 500.

Some hosting also have ignore_user_abort/set_time_limit in their disabled_functions list for that same reason.

**Update:** Changed Many to Some. Guess the hosts I use are pretty different than what people normally use.

Comment: The second point is great. I just realized a warning in the [set_time_limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php), however that is also deprecated. However, [disable_functions()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) might be the answer. I'll wait 24 hours to see if anyone offers any other answer.